# Get all dataframe based in certain value in dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a `DataFrame`  looks something like this :

```
       import numpy as np
       import pandas as pd

       df=pd.DataFrame([['d',5,6],['a',6,6],['index',5,8],['b',3,1],['b',5,6],['index',6,7],
            ['e',2,3],['c',5,6],['index',5,8]],columns=['A','B','C'])
```

I want to select all the lines that are between `index` and create many  dataframes

I want to obtain all as :

dataframe1:

```
         A  B   C
 1       a  6   6
 2   index  5   8
 3      3   b   3
```

dataframe 2

```
                A   B   C
         4      b   5   6
         5  index   6   7
         6      c   2   3
```

datframe3:

```
                   A   B    C
              7    c    5   6
              8 index   5   8
              9    4    3   1
```

dataframe4 :

```
                            A  B   C

                     11    5    2   3
                     12 index   4   2
                     13   1     2   5
```

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean by "all the lines between `index`". If you mean the rows between those rows containing the value `index` at column `A` then they don't match your output dataframes...

Comment: I don't get where DataFrame 4 is coming from when you have only provided 9 rows.  Also, this doesn't seem like it's between `index` values, since it *includes* index values

Comment: How did you get these 4 dataframes in the first place? What is your code? You say that you want to create many dataframes, apparently the 4 dataframes but then you say that you don't know where dataframe 4 is coming from...

Comment: I don't see the logic of your desired output dataframes. For example, in dataframe1: why is the third row given by `3 b 3` instead of `b 3 1`? I don't see how it is related to "all the lines that are between `index`". i think your question is unclear.

Comment: Next time try to formulate correctly your question. Based on the chosen answer, the 4 dataframes that you provided in your question is NOT the desired output, which is not clear when you write "I want to obtain all as ".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
index_list = df.index[df['A'] == 'index'].tolist() # create a list of the index where df['A']=='index'
new_df = [] # empty list for dataframes
for i in index_list: # for loop
    try:
        new_df.append(df.iloc[i-1:i+2])
    except:
        pass
```

this creates a list of dataframes you can call them by `new_df[0]` `new_df[1]` or use a loop to print them out:

```
for i in range(len(new_df)):
    print(f'{new_df[i]}\n')

       A  B  C
1      a  6  6
2  index  5  8
3      b  3  1

       A  B  C
4      b  5  6
5  index  6  7
6      e  2  3

       A  B  C
7      c  5  6
8  index  5  8
```